# MySQL: connection lost after 5 minutes

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian

I'm using web app (AppSheet.com) to connect to my MySQL database and export data from this app to my mysql.
I don't have ability to edit the app (connection, queries etc.), but I have full root access to the remote mysql server.

The app connects successfully, creates first table and inserts rows one by one. After 5 minutes I get an error from the app saying that it can't find the table it was writing to and the export stops.

I was trying to play with those mysql config variables:

```
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
max_execution_time = 28800
delayed_insert_timeout = 28800
net_read_timeout = 28800
net_write_timeout = 28800
connect_timeout = 10
```

but witout any luck. App admins are not helpful too.

mysql error log does not have any new entries.

How can debug and find what really happens and why the connection is lost?
How can I make sure that there is no time limit?

Comment: I suspect your web server is timing out, what do the server logs tell you?

Comment: `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`.  What version of MySQL?  Were you doing nothing no SQL during the 5 minutes?